# Sessão do codeigniter expirando depois de uma ação

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

Eu fiz um painel administrativo usando `CodeIgniter` e toda hora a sessão fica expirando, assim, redirecionando para a tela de login. Toda vez por exemplo, que eu edito uma categoria, após editada e clicar em outro link do menu, o sistema redireciona para tela de login novamente.

**config.php (arquivo padrão do CodeIgniter)**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Não sei se essas configurações tem haver, pois é muito rápido essa "expiração" de sessão.

O link do menu **http://localhost/RP/admin/banners**

**user_model.php (arquivo responsável pelo login)**

```php
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function DadosUser()
    {
        $sessao = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        if (!$sessao AND empty($sessao)) {
            redirect(base_url('login'));  
        } 

        $this->db->where('id', $sessao);
        $user = $this->db->get('admin_users');

        if ($user->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $user->row();
        }

        redirect(base_url('login'));
    }
}
```

**categorias_model.php (model responsável pela categoria)**

```php
<?php
class Categorias_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function NovaCategoria()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = '../uploads/banners';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|bmp|jpg|jpeg|pjpeg';

        $categoria = $this->input->post('categoria');
        $ordem = $this->input->post('ordem');

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT (MAX(codigo_categoria) + 1) AS codigo FROM Categorias");
        $novoCodigo = $query->row()->codigo;

        $data = array(
            'codigo_categoria' => $novoCodigo,
            'nome_categoria' => $categoria,
            'ordem' => $ordem
        );

        if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {

                $upload = $this->upload->data();

                $data['imagem'] = $upload['file_name'];
            }
        }

        if ($this->db->insert('Categorias', $data)) {
            return '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Categoria cadastrada com sucesso!</div>';
        }

        return '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Erro ao cadastrar categoria.</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, você poderia mostrar mais partes do código, como a parte de login, editar categoria e um método de qualquer link do menu, pois só analisado esse trecho de cofiguração não dar para saber, uma vez que ele está correto e definindo a duração 2 horas para as sessões, isso é definido na seguinte linha: $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;//segundos

Comment: @YurePereira coloquei na publicação

Comment: CI dar pau não é novidade, hehehehe

Comment: Ele está caindo no:
`if(!$sessao AND empty($sessao)) redirect(base_url('login'));`

ou no:
`redirect(base_url('login'));`?

Faz um echo do seu `$this->session->userdata('user_id');` na sua view, para ver se ele está mantendo o valor.

--

Só uma obs, retornar HTML em um model é uma péssima prática, você deve usar HTML apenas nas views.

Answer (score 1):

Para tentar resolver esse problema tenta aumentar o tempo a qual é feito a atualização das sessões na variável de configuração `sess_time_to_update`, assim:

```
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 86400;// 24 horas
```

Verifica também as configurações de cookie no navegador onde você está testando seu sistema, pois o Codeigniter usa cookies para gravar as sessões criadas com ele.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que mudar no application > config > config.php

```
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 172800; // 48 horas por exemplo
```

Tente user as sessões usando database como consta na documentação, é mais fácil e você pode através dessa galera gerar logs guardados e controle de usuários.

Link da documentação, lembrando que o codeigniter já está em sua versão 3.1 (no momento dessa resposta):

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session